# What's the easiest way to setup Protractor e2e tests to run nightly?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, nightly-build

Like many angularjs developers I have a test suite of protractor e2e tests.  The test suite takes about half an hour to an hour to run.  I would like to be able to run the tests nightly using some kind of cloud based setup, if possible.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to host and run the protractor tests.

Is there a common cloud setup or some easy setup for running protractor e2e tests either on check-in or for a nightly build?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (I don't say the best way) that I'm using currently is setup task scheduler job that is run on remote machine. This Task Scheduler job is triggered in 2AM and run windows batch file with few commands: first one pulls last version from git, second changes directory to where my automated tests can be run and last one is running tests (more precisely the smoke suite):

```
git pull origin develop
cd C:\arkcase-test\protractor
protractor protractor.chrome.conf.js --suite=smoke
```

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins job is fine for this you can trigger a mail saying build success or failure after this nightly run .

You can even attach your HTML report in the mail .

How ever this slave PC should be online connected running the jenkins client.